# Connecting Angular to nodejs and mysql

Tags: node.js, angular

I am connecting my angular file index.html but when running on the server web page doesn't display anything. It runs ok but my front-end form built on angular is not showing.

Here is my server script:

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var connection = require('./config');
var app = express();

var authenticateController = require('./controllers/authenticate-controller');
var registerController = require('./controllers/register-controller');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {  
    res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "./index.html" );  
});  
app.use

app.get('/login.html', function (req, res) {  
    res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "login.html" );  
})  

/* route to handle login and registration */
// app.post('/api/register',registerController.register);
// app.post('/api/authenticate',authenticateController.authenticate);

console.log(authenticateController);
// app.post('/controllers/register-controller', registerController.register);
// app.post('/controllers/authenticate-controller', authenticateController.authenticate);
app.listen(8012);
```

here is my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>FirstApp</title>
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

I have made a register component name register.component.html...

```
 <form action="/controllers/register-controller" method="POST">

     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Your Email" name="name">
    </div>      
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" name="password">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I've edited your question to improve grammar and structure it better, but it's still hard to understand. Please edit it further to clarify: "It runs ok" = what runs ok? Do I understand correctly that your html by itself works normally, but when you try to serve it using node.js, a blank page is shown? What "component" have you registered? An angular component? If so, where is its code? register.component.html that you have shown is some plain html...

Comment: What exactly works for you ("runs ok")? Is it index.html? How does it work if there's no `script` tag in it? What the form (the third code snippet) has to do with the problem?

Comment: I also strongly recommend you taking the https://stackoverflow.com/tour and reading "asking" in the https://stackoverflow.com/help Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, first things first: **you have to connect your js to your html so that Angular works.**

Look at this minimal example from [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/setting-up-angular-from-scratch-1f518c65d8ab):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello, Angular</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-main>Loading...</app-main>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('dist/main.js').catch(function (err) {
          console.error(err);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

they got `script`s that are actually angular code + their code. You won't have this code literally, but you must have scripts somewhere.

PS I'd recommend to try to make it work as a static html first (using some hosting or some out-of-box server) and build your own server afterwards.